# Search issues with Sphinx (installed with Mediawiki)

Tags: php, mediawiki, sphinx

error] [696cbd84] /wiki/index.php?search=wer&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go ErrorException from line 771 of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\extensions\SphinxSearch\sphinxapi.php: PHP Deprecated: DEPRECATED: Do not call this method or, even better, use SphinxQL instead of an API

## 0 [internal function]: MWExceptionHandler::handleError(16384, 'DEPRECATED: Do ...', 'C:\inetpub\wwwr...', 771, Array)

## 1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\extensions\SphinxSearch\sphinxapi.php(771): trigger_error('DEPRECATED: Do ...', 16384)

## 2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\extensions\SphinxSearch\SphinxMWSearch.php(152): SphinxClient->SetMatchMode(6)

## 3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\extensions\SphinxSearch\SphinxMWSearch.php(69): SphinxMWSearch->prepareSphinxClient('wer')

## 4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\specials\SpecialSearch.php(256): SphinxMWSearch->searchText('wer')

## 5 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\specials\SpecialSearch.php(200): SpecialSearch->showResults('wer')

## 6 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\specials\SpecialSearch.php(117): SpecialSearch->goResult('wer')

## 7 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\specialpage\SpecialPage.php(384): SpecialSearch->execute(NULL)

## 8 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\specialpage\SpecialPageFactory.php(582): SpecialPage->run(NULL)

## 9 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\MediaWiki.php(267): SpecialPageFactory::executePath(Object(Title), Object(RequestContext))

## 10 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\MediaWiki.php(566): MediaWiki->performRequest()

## 11 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\MediaWiki.php(414): MediaWiki->main()

## 12 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\index.php(41): MediaWiki->run()

## 13 {main}

[error-json] {"id":"696cbd84","type":"ErrorException","file":"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\extensions\SphinxSearch\sphinxapi.php","line":771,"message":"PHP Deprecated: DEPRECATED: Do not call this method or, even better, use SphinxQL instead of an API","url":"/wiki/index.php?search=wer&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go","backtrace":

[{"function":"handleError","class":"MWExceptionHandler","type":"::","args":["integer","string","string","integer","array"]},{"file":"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\extensions\SphinxSearch\sphinxapi.php","line":771,"function":"trigger_error","args":["string","integer"]},{"file":"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\extensions\SphinxSearch\SphinxMWSearch.php","line":152,"function":"SetMatchMode","class":"SphinxClient","type":"->","args":["integer"]},{"file":"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\extensions\SphinxSearch\SphinxMWSearch.php","line":69,"function":"prepareSphinxClient","class":"SphinxMWSearch","type":"->","args":["string"]},{"file":"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\specials\SpecialSearch.php","line":256,"function":"searchText","class":"SphinxMWSearch","type":"->","args":["string"]},{"file":"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\specials\SpecialSearch.php","line":200,"function":"showResults","class":"SpecialSearch","type":"->","args":["string"]},{"file":"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\specials\SpecialSearch.php","line":117,"function":"goResult","class":"SpecialSearch","type":"->","args":["string"]},{"file":"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\specialpage\SpecialPage.php","line":384,"function":"execute","class":"SpecialSearch","type":"->","args":["NULL"]},{"file":"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\specialpage\SpecialPageFactory.php","line":582,"function":"run","class":"SpecialPage","type":"->","args":["NULL"]},{"file":"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\MediaWiki.php","line":267,"function":"executePath","class":"SpecialPageFactory","type":"::","args":["Title","RequestContext"]},{"file":"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\MediaWiki.php","line":566,"function":"performRequest","class":"MediaWiki","type":"->","args":[]},{"file":"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\includes\MediaWiki.php","line":414,"function":"main","class":"MediaWiki","type":"->","args":[]},{"file":"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wiki\index.php","line":41,"function":"run","class":"MediaWiki","type":"->","args":[]}]}
SphinxSearch query: wer
Query MATRIX_WIKI (17) (slave): SELECT /* LCStoreDB::get 192.168.51.209 */ lc_value FROM `MX_l10n_cache` WHERE lc_lang = 'en' AND lc_key = 'messages:searchprofile-articles' LIMIT 1
Query MATRIX_WIKI (18) (slave): SELECT /* LCStoreDB::get 192.168.51.209 */ lc_value FROM `MX_l10n_cache` WHERE lc_lang = 'en' AND lc_key = 'messages:searchprofile-articles-tooltip' LIMIT 1
Query MATRIX_WIKI (19) (slave): SELECT /* LCStoreDB::get 192.168.51.209 */ lc_value FROM `MX_l10n_cache` WHERE lc_lang = 'en' AND lc_key = 'messages:searchprofile-images' LIMIT 1
Query MATRIX_WIKI (20) (slave): SELECT /* LCStoreDB::get 192.168.51.209 */ lc_value FROM `MX_l10n_cache` WHERE lc_lang = 'en' AND lc_key = 'messages:searchprofile-images-tooltip' LIM

Answer (score 0):

You could set your installation to ignore depreciation messages

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php